# Django: loop over query and return newest related object

Tags: django, django-views

I have `Unit` in my app that creating `Order`s and `Report`s each week, I want view that results as table containing name of `Unit`s in first column and 3 newest `Order`s and `Report`s in next 6 column. so i need query of Units and 3 of related Order and Report to each Unit.
I try to use `prefetch_related` in this way but don't know how to limit it (and even make it work)

```
Unit.objects.filter(parent__name__contains="x").prefetch_related('order_set', 'reportfrom_set').order_by('order__date','reportfrom__submit_datetime')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What database are you using? Optimizing this prefetches will be different on each database backend.

Comment: now in development I'm using Sqlite, for first release I plane switching to Mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method will execute a database query for each *lookup* you want to prefetch. Basically, here, Django will execute a first database query to get your `Unit` instances and then two other queries to get the `Order` and `Report` instances.

So, once your `Unit.obects.filter(...).prefetch_related(...)` queryset is executed, each `Unit` instance will have its related `Order` and `Report` objects cached (no more database queries required to fetch these data).

---

### views.py

Since Django 1.7, the `prefetch_related()` method accepts a [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object. This `Prefetch` object has a `queryset` attribute that helps you to filter/order the related objects:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    units = Unit.objects.all().prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'orders_set',
            queryset=Order.objects.all().order_by('date'),
            to_attr='prefetched_orders'
        ),
        Prefetch(
            'report_set',
            queryset=Report.objects.all().order_by('submit_datetime'),
            to_attr='prefetched_reports'
        )
    )

    for unit in units:
        unit.prefetched_orders = unit.prefetched_orders[:3]
        unit.prefetched_reports = unit.prefetched_reports[:3]

    return render_to_response('template.html', context={
        'units': units
    })
```

The `to_attr` attribute let us store the related objects in a Python `list`.
So, [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) those lists will not call the database anymore.

Now you have your newest orders and reports and you can build the object you want.

---

### template.html

You can iterate over your units like that (the `units` collection being the template context's `units` object):

```
{%  for unit in units %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

and then, you can browse the previously prefetched objects (tabular design with this code):

```
<table>
{%  for unit in units %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ unit.field_to_display }}</td>
        {% for order in unit.prefetched_orders %}
            <td>{{ order.field_to_display}}</td>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for report in unit.prefetched_reports %}
            <td>{{ report.field_to_display}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

More info about the templating language can be found in the [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language).

Comment: unfortunately, slicing that queries will perform another query.

Comment: Then, we can take advantage of the to_attr attribute of the Prefetch object, to assign the queryset result to a list. Splicing the list should then be ok, no?

Comment: That's the main problem, splicing that list for every `Unit` model.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas and @GwynBleidD. Seems OK but I'm afraid of performance lake. please explain about number of more queries this answer perform. Is it order of Unit numbers?

Comment: EDIT: and please explain how to access related Orders and Reports in templates?

Comment: @BehnamHeydari post updated. I added a (basic) template example and the to_attr usage. This should perform some Python slicing. So no db involved after the first evaluation of your queryset.